# error during gcc 4.7.3 compilation

Tags: gcc, compilation, gcc-warning, gcc4.7

I am trying to compile local version of gcc 4.7.3 on the cluster.
For configuration:

`./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/gcc-4.7.3 --with-gmp=$HOME/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=$HOME/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=$HOME/opt/mpc --with-libelf=$HOME/opt/libelf`

while compiling I got:

> /home/users/didymos/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.a(pprime_p.o):(.text+0x448):
>   undefined reference to `__multi3'
>
> /home/users/didymos/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.a(mod_1.o):(.text+0x158):
>   undefined reference to `__multi3'
>
> /home/users/didymos/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.a(mod_1.o):(.text+0x1b8):
>   undefined reference to `__multi3'
>
> /home/users/didymos/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.a(mod_1.o):(.text+0x358):
>   undefined reference to `__multi3'
>
> /home/users/didymos/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.a(pre_mod_1.o):(.text+0x74):
>   undefined reference to `__multi3'
>
> /home/users/didymos/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.a(mod_1_1.o):(.text+0x60): more
>   undefined references to `__multi3' follow
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[8]: *** [libjavamath.la] Error 1
>
> make[8]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath/native/jni/java-math'
>
> make[7]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[7]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath/native/jni'
>
> make[6]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[6]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath/native'
>
> make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[5]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath'
>
> make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[4]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava'
>
> make[3]: *** [multi-do] Error 1
>
> make[3]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
>
> make[2]: *** [all-multi] Error 2
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
>
> make[1]: *** [all-target-libjava] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>
> libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libgfortran.a
>
> libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgfortran.la" && ln -s
>   "../libgfortran.la" "libgfortran.la" )
>
> make[6]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/nof/libgfortran'
>
> make[5]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/nof/libgfortran'
>
> make[4]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgfortran'
>
> make[3]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgfortran'
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch/powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgfortran'
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/users/didymos/opt/gcc-4.3.7-scratch'
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `libgfortran` would be the GNU fortran library, it appears that something you're using requires it, have you installed GFortran and its associated libraries?

Comment: You didn't show enough of your log.  There are no errors there.

Comment: yes I have gfortran and it seems its running ok

Comment: I have updated error message - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that libgmp depends on? If libgmp depends on a library A, then most likely the undefined symbols would be in A.

If you have manually compiled libgmp from source, Can you add the configure command in the question?